# "no buffer space available" PDO error

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

Every now and then, one of my servers breaks down with this error message:

> symfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php
>   line 40 {"exception":"[object] (PDOException(code: 7): SQLSTATE[08006]
>   [7] could not connect to server: No buffer space available

For no reason I can figure out. It then catches itself again after a while.

Apparently the error is on the DB side, because different applications all tend to fail. Despite extensive Google search, I couldn't find anything helpful, except that I'm not the only person experiencing this problem.

I'm using a Symfony2 application with a PostgreSQL backend, not sure if that matters. I don't see much load or other performance issues, my various memory settings in both PHP and Postgres are ample, and I don't see any useful error messages in any of the logs. So I'm completely lost and even a pointer into the right general direction would be most appreciated.

Comment: You can check mysql.ini buffer size and increase that.

Comment: As mentioned above, I use Postgres, not MySQL. I have shared_buffers = 512MB there. If that's not enough, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Just a try by making shared_buffers = 750MB.

Comment: Blind try or are you reasonably sure that this is the setting causing the problems? I'm trying, since this is a Heisenbug, it will be a day or two until I'm more or less sure if it helps or not.

Comment: Looks like an operating system error. Perhaps you can check this: http://serverfault.com/questions/614453/no-buffer-space-available-on-connect

Comment: Please post the related code otherwise we can't help you. Also, we have the same name, hello Tom. :D

Comment: I can't post related code or I would've. The error message does not show which request triggers the error.

Comment: Thanks @user3584460. I'll investigate that. The system is running on a VPS, so a system resource shortage could be the answer.

Comment: `could not connect to server: No buffer space available` This is an OS error. a socket could not be opened because of buffer shortage. You probably have too many connections open, and perform too few read()s on them.

Answer (score 0):

The right solution as in the comments, so I'm just writing it up as an answer:

Increasing shared_buffers in the PostgreSQL configuration made the issue go away.